# Resuable Content in a WebPart

Tags: 2010, html-editor

I have an HTML Editor web part. I want to add some resuable content to it but it is greyed out.

> Note   Although you also use the HTML Editor to edit content that is
>   contained by a Content Editor Web Part, reusable content is not
>   available for use in a Web Part.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-reusable-content-HA010163838.aspx

Does this hold true for 2010? Is there any way round it?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I verified that Reusable Content is available for Content Editor Web Part also. Please ensure following:

•   You have enabled publishing infrastructure or start with publishing site template.

•   Ensure Reusable Content list is created at root web level

•   To use it in rich text field of SharePoint site, the publishing features must be enabled at sub sites level too.

•   If you are using rich text field (and not CEWP), also make sure the rich text field you have is "full HTML with Formatting and constraints of publishing"

UPDATE:
I also found that it will be enabled only when you are using the field: "full HTML with Formatting and constraints of publishing" Or you insert HTML Editor web part (I assume Content Editor Web Part) inside above field while editing. So I think ultimately it boils down to the fact that it is enabled only when you are editing content of a field: "full HTML with Formatting and constraints of publishing"

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of (but I'm not on a 2010 Enterprise environment yet), the reusable HTML must be used in page layouts that have the rich text areas.  You'd just need to move to such a layout and include the HTML editor web part content within that rich text area.

Comment: We are using publishing templates so we use the HTML Contet Editor to allow putting content in the differnt regions.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found is to use the content editor web part text link to a simple HTML page which is uploaded to the document library. 
eg
<head><body>
[content]
</body>
</html>